# Correct use of Parallel for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In this example, is this the correct use of the `Parallel.For` loop if I want to limit the number of threads that can perform the function `DoWork` to ten at a time? Will other threads be blocked until one of the ten threads becomes available? If not, what is a better multi-threaded solution that would still let me execute that function 6000+ times?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadExample ex = new ThreadExample(); 
    }
}

public class ThreadExample
{
    int limit = 6411; 

    public ThreadExample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting threads...");
        int temp = 0; 
        Parallel.For(temp, limit, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
        {
            DoWork(temp);
            temp++; 
        }); 
    }

    public void DoWork(int info)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(50); //doing some work here. 

        int num = info * 5; 

        Console.WriteLine("Thread: {0}      Result: {1}", info.ToString(), num.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp++` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, it is not thread safe, but has it meaning in this contest? How works Parallel.For?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What do you mean?  The intention of the programmer is clear; he wants to count the number of completed tasks.  What actually happens is not the same thing, due to the race conditions that will possibly result in the counter not being properly incremented.  The use of `interlocked.Exchange` would solve that.  As for `Paralle.For`, it's a `for` loop for which the iterations are executed (to a certain degree) by multiple threads, in parallel.

Comment: @Servy You have typo `Interlocked.Increment` must be. But is not necessary too, as described in `Mattias Buelens` answer loop counter is organized internally and `temp` not actual in this context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the `i` passed to the lambda function as index. `Parallel.For` relieves you from the hassle of working with the loop counter, but you need to use it!

```
    Parallel.For(0, limit, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
    {
        DoWork(i);
    });
```

As for your other questions:

- Yes, this will correctly limit the amount of threads working simultaneously.
- There are no threads being blocked. The iterations are queued and as soon as a thread becomes available, it takes the next iteration (in a synchronized manner) from the queue to process.

Comment: MaxDegreeOfParallelism  is what your looking for

Comment: @MicahArmantrout He was already using that in the OP; that wasn't what gave him trouble.  This answer correctly identifies the problem with the OP's code.

Comment: This is a problem with the OPs solution but it does not answer any of the particular questions asked (except for "is this ok?").

Comment: @Servy I miss understood ... this is still the correct answer